# Highchart plot points are being displayed incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've never had this happen before and I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. As you can see, even though point A's datapoints is lower then B's, it is appearing above it(first screen shot). What's weird is that when I hide line B (2nd screen shot), line A correctly moves to the right position.

[image: 2 charts superimposed on one another showing incorrect plot points]

[image: when line B is hidden, line A correctly displays its plot points]

I put together a jsfiddle to demonstrate this issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/qwfZ9/1813/

And the code below:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{
        renderTo:"ChartArea",
        defaultSeriesType:"line",
        zoomType:"x",
        plotBackgroundColor:"#c8c8c8",
        backgroundColor:"#d5d5d5"
    },
    title:{
        text:"TEST"
    },
    series:[{
        name:"A",
        data:[21,21,21,21,23,23,26,24,24,24,24,26,26,21,19,19,19,23,23,23,21,22,22,22,21,16],
        pointStart:1314316800000,
        pointInterval:86400000,
        stack:0,
        type:"line",
        multiplier:1,
        dashStyle:"solid",
        color:"#AA4643"
    },{
        name:"B",
        data:[51,51,51,51,52,53,50,47,47,47,47,46,46,42,41,41,41,67,65,66,50,53,52,53,64,59],
        pointStart:1314316800000,
        pointInterval:86400000,
        stack:0,
        type:"line",
        multiplier:1,
        dashStyle:"solid",
        color:"#89A54E"}],
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            stacking:"normal",
            borderColor:"black",
            shadow:false,
            borderWidth:0},
        area:{
            stacking:"normal",
            shadow:false,
            fillOpacity:0}},
    LastUpdated:0,
    colors:["#000000"],
    yAxis:{
        title:{
            text:"Test Counts"
        },
        labels:{
            rotation:0,
            align:"right"
        },
        plotOptions:[{color:"#000000",
                      width:2,
                      value:0,
                      id:"plotline-1"}],
        startOnTick:true,
        showFirstLabel:true,
        stackLabels:{
            enabled:true,
                     style:{
                         color:"black"}},
        min:0,
        max:100},
    xAxis:{
        title:{
            text:"Time"},
        type:"datetime",
        maxZoom:86400000,
        tickInterval:86400000,
        labels:{
            rotation:-40,
            align:"right",}},
    credits:{
        enabled:false},
    ZoomTypeChanger:null,
    yExtreme:null});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `stacking:"normal"` from your `series` value for `plotOptions` seems to fix the issue:

```
plotOptions:{
    series:{
        // stacking:"normal",
        borderColor:"black",
        shadow:false,
        borderWidth:0},
    area:{
        stacking:"normal",
        shadow:false,
        fillOpacity:0}},
```

You *may* want to [file a bug report](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues) if the documentation does not suggest that there is some reason for the shift.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This fixed it! copy-paste fail on my part ^_^